# How to group class names together in SQL Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT students.UserID, students.FName, students.LName, GROUP_CONCAT(classes.ClassName SEPARATOR ',') AS Classes
FROM classassociation
JOIN students
    ON classassociation.UserID = Students.UserID
JOIN classes
    ON classassociation.ClassID = classes.ClassID
WHERE classassociation.UserID = 3
GROUP BY ClassName;
```

Here is my Join statement, i'm trying to output:

```
User ID | Name      | Classes
1        John smith   Science, Maths
```

Currently it outputs as

```
  User ID | FName | LName  | Classes
     1      John    smith    Science
     1      John    smith    Maths
```

I'm trying to output it as a  HTML table so changing how it outputed would save some space and look more presentable.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why are you grouping by classname?  It appears that userid is the unique key.  The relationship is one user to many classes and therefore you should be grouping by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT students.UserID,
    CONCAT(students.FName,' ', students.LName) AS Name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(classes.ClassName SEPARATOR ',') AS Classes
FROM classassociation
JOIN students
    ON classassociation.UserID = Students.UserID
JOIN classes
    ON classassociation.ClassID = classes.ClassID
WHERE classassociation.UserID = 3
GROUP BY UserID, CONCAT(students.FName, students.LName);
```

It looks like you want the first and last name together in one **column**, so for those, use CONCAT. The classes you are correct to use GROUP CONCAT because you want multiple **rows** grouped together.

Then you just need to adjust your GROUP BY statement. Any column you have listed in your SELECT statement needs to be there, except for the one(s) being aggregated. In your case, classes is being aggregated, so you can exclude that from the GROUP BY. User ID and both of your name columns are not being aggregated, so those should be listed.

Comment: How do i add a separator so the first name and last name have a space between them?

Comment: You just have to put that in the CONCAT. I made an update to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
GROUP BY ClassName;
```

Do:

```
GROUP BY students.UserID, students.FName, students.LName
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the formatting.... I am new to this stackoverflow.

Here is the the code which will give you perfect result

Here is the details:

I created temp table just to get you demo

replace my column name with your colum name..

insert into #temp values ('1', 'John', 'smith', 'science')

insert into #temp values('1', 'John', 'Smith', 'Maths')

select

id

,fname + ' ' + LNAME AS NAME

,STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + ' ' + T2.Class

FROM #temp T2

WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID

FOR XML PATH('')),1,2, '') AS CLASS

FROM #temp T1

GROUP BY ID, FNAME, LNAME

If you have any question please let me know 
Thanks